# Google apps script - Folder as a script container

Tags: google-apps-script

Is it possible to restrict the reach of a Google Apps Script to a given Google Drive folder?

I'm creating a stand alone apps script that will be hosted as a web app.
The goal of the script is to list all the sub-folders contained inside the folder (the root folder) where the stand alone script is saved and return a JSON with information about those sub-folders and the files that they contain.

**notes**:

1. The name or the id of the root folder is unknown as the script will be distributed to Google Drive users and I want to allow them to save the script inside any folder they would like to.
2. Although the root folder can have any name or any hierarchical position inside the user's Google Drive folders tree, I'm planning on enforcing a predefined naming structure for the sub-folders.

I thought about two approaches to solve this, but I do not know which one is possible and what Classes and Methods to use.

1)The first approach would be to restrict the script reach to it's container folder, therefore the call to DocsList.getFolders(), would return an array of folders objects just for the folders (sub-folders) contained by the root folder.

**Question:** Does Google Apps Script provide a Class or Method to restrict the reach of a stand alone script, as described above?

2) Get the name or id of the root folder containing the script and using it retrieve the sub-folders and their files.

**Question** Does Google Apps Script provide a Method to get the name or the id of the folder that contains the script?

Thanks in advance for any help or tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of those are currently possible. You can write a ui to ask the user for the folder. The google picker now supports picking folders.